# VB: Instancing object in a class and using in in methods

Tags: vb.net, object, scope, streamwriter

So I'm trying to write a class that allows me to write stuff to a file at every tick event of a Timer object. My form also has On and Off Buttons which I would like to use to ideally instance the Writer object and close it respectively.  I am having trouble getting my head around the scope in which the objects need to be created and can be accessed.

I have included code relevant to my problem below.

The problem with it is that oStreamWriter is scoped to the Set() method and not accessible by the subs that ask it to do the writing or ask it to close.

I want to make a class of this process for 2 reasons:
1) I want to avoid using the streamwriter object in my form code (isolating UI code)
2) I could not instance the StreamWriter in the OnButton_Click() sub because that meant i couldn't access it in the OffButt_Click() sub. So i had to instance it in the Form_Load() sub which meant that once i press the off button and close the streamwriter, pressing the o button referenced an object that was now closed.

My class code is as follows:

```
Public Class FileWriterClass

    ' dimension private properties
    Private pProperty As String ' dimension the property to write
    Private filenameString As String

    Public path As String = "C:\somefolder"

    ' Use set()and get() to set the property or get the property 
    Property TheProperty() As String

        Get
            Return pProperty
        End Get

        Set(ByVal inputValue As String)
            pProperty = inputValue
            Select Case pProperty
                Case "1"
                    filenameString = path + "\A.txt"
                Case "2"
                    filenameString = path+ "\B.txt"
            End Select

            ' instance the StreamWriter object
            oStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(filenameString, True)

        End Set

    End Property

    Public Sub WriteToFile(ByVal someString As String, ByVal anotherString As String)
        oStreamWriter .WriteLine(someString + ", " + anotherString + ", " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Sub CloseWriter()
        oStreamWriter .Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your streamwriter object needs a class level reference like you do with filename:

```
Public Class FileWriterClass

' dimension private properties
Private pProperty As String ' dimension the property to write
Private filenameString As String

private mySR as StreamWriter

Public path As String = "C:\somefolder"
```

I would open it as needed to write and otherwise keep it closed, but it is hard to tell what you are doing...`pairWriter` for instance is never declared.

Alternatively, create it when the class is created as it doesnt seem very useful without a filename etc.

```
  private mySR as StreamWriter

  Public Sub New(filename As String)
      mySr = New StreamWriter(filename, ....)
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Ive been trying class level declaration but As Object rather than StreamWriter. pairWriter was typo should be oStreamWriter. I will try this now and post results

Comment: Thanks, this did exactly what I needed. Did not realize that simply declaring the variable as an object wouldnt work but actually needed the specific object it was going to be.

Comment: we arent declaring it `As Object`, we are saying WHEN we go to use this it will be a StreamWriter.  That part creates the object reference, while `mySR = New StreamWriter(filename, ....)` creates the instance.  The reference where it is gives it `scope` beyond the procedure we instance it in.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare StreamWriter object as global section to access eveywhere in your code, but there is also one more possible way to access the same object, what I mean is that you can send the StreamWriter object as a parameter to any methods where you want to use it.